# Running suspend function in a loop postvalue is called only once

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-livedata, android-viewmodel

I want to run a suspend function in a loop.

It is working fine, but `postValue` is not updating value every time. It calls the observer only once. What can be done here?

```kotlin
jobSearch = viewModelScope.launch(exceptionHandler) {
    for (category in (searchCategories.value?.data ?: emptyList())) {
        searchResponse.postValue(Resource.loading(null))
        val response =
            searchResultSource.getSearchResultFromRepo(
                category?.id,
                searchTerm,
                1,
                Constants.PAGE_SIZE_SEARCH
            )
        response?.let {
            searchResponse.postValue(Resource.sucess(response))
        } ?: run {
            searchResponse.postValue(Resource.error("Something Went Wrong"))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here? When you post a Success or Error result, the next iteration of the loop again posts a Loading status. So you will always see a loading status until the loop ends.

Comment: no its working fine just that post is not triggering observer everytime

Comment: This seems messed up .. Why don't u add the problem with question which you are trying to fix by using for loop .. there can be a better approach to do that . The ways its written right now does not make much sense  you are just posting the response further How will client know which request was used for this response ..

Comment: LiveData has no buffer--it will drop values without ever emitting them to observers if new values come in fast enough. You can't use it like a queue of work like this. It's hard to say the proper way to do this because it's not clear from your code exactly what you're trying to do, as it's illogical the way it is now. Side note: `?.let {} ?: run` is a very error-prone pattern (you can easily accidentally run both "branches") and not good for readability either. You can replace `let` with `also` to prevent the error-proneness, but for readability you should just use if/else instead.

Answer (score 0):

The `postValue` method enqueues the new value in the `Main Thread`. If you call this method before the Main Thread delivers this value to the observer, it will replace the old value with the new one. So your observer always reads the last emitted value. You need to replace your `searchResponse.postValue` calls with the following codes to deliver all emitted values to the observer:

```
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(() -> searchResponse.setValue(Resource.loading(null)));


new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(() -> searchResponse.setValue(Resource.sucess(response)));


new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(() -> searchResponse.setValue(Resource.error("Something Went Wrong")));
```

Comment: but thats OS specific code which I don't want in viewmodel.

Comment: ViewModel and ViewModelScope are Android Specific classes too. postValue method is also an Android Specific method. It emittes the value to the Main Thread

Comment: This approach won't change the behavior from `postValue`. It's basically what `postValue` does under the hood anyway. These values are still going to overwrite each other on the next loop of the main thread.

Comment: Test it before judging it. My approach emits all values to the main thread without dropping the old ones. @Tenfour04

Comment: In isolation your code may post these in sequence, but what I mean is it doesn’t fix the root problem in the OP’s code, since they are iterating a list and posting all these updates at once. They will be getting lots of interleaved different loading and result states from all the different fetches.

Comment: is there any other solution to this?

Comment: In LiveData, no but you can use other libraries like RxJava @amodkanthe

Comment: Okay I found a way to do it :)